# How do I increase framerate for parallax scrolling?

Tags: google-chrome, timeline, parallax

My frame rate for this parallax is too low.  When I look at how [Apple is doing it](http://www.apple.com/iphone/features/), their frame rate stays very close to 60.

I took a timeline snapshot of my scrolling and the big offender is the "Paint" for "Image Resize (cache)".  Is there a way to reduce that?